# ObjectId is not a function in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, backend, objectid

I just saw a blog on how to retrive a particular document by the ID of the document.

But here the code just does not seem to work for some reason.

It works always, can you people tell me why this is happening?

Code:

```js
app.post('/api/get-list-data', (req, res) => {
  const listID = req.body.listID;
  client.connect(async err => {
    const collection = client.db('to-do-lists').collection('made');
    const data = await collection.findOne({
      _id: new ObjectId()
    })

    if (data) {
      res.send(data);
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: false
      });
    }
  })
})
```

Any help would be greatful!

Comment: Even if it would work, you would never find anything because you're trying to find a document for an ObjectId that was just created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my issue by getting the ObjectId in the top of the page like this:

```js
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow example:

```
import { ObjectId } from "bson"

app.post('/api/get-list-data', (req, res) => {
  const listID = req.body.listID;
  client.connect(async err => {
    const collection = client.db('to-do-lists').collection('made');
    const data = await collection.findOne({
      '_id': new BSON.ObjectId('3r6a9f26x')
    }).toArray();
    if (data) {
      res.send(data);
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: false
      });
    }
  })
})
```

**Reference:**

- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-use-objectid-search-from-webhook-in-mongodb/102081

Answer (score 2):

I am using `node version v18.16.0` and mongodb `"mongodb": "^5.5.0"`. `new` keyword is required as shown in below code. Sample: `new ObjectId(_id)`

```
const { MongoClient,  ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const config = require("../config.json");

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(config.mongoDb.dbUrl);
const db = mongoClient.db(config.mongoDb.dbName);
await db.collection(config.mongoDb.collectionName).findOne({ "_id": new ObjectId(_id)});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectId` is a global in `mongo-cli` but not in the `node` environment.
You can use exported function `ObjectId` from the `mongodb` package to create a new `ObjectId` instance.

```
        const data = await collection.findOne({ _id: mongo.ObjectId() })
```

You may also pass a valid hex representation of an objectID as an argument (assuming that listID is one)

```
        const data = await collection.findOne({ _id: mongo.ObjectId(listID) })
```

You also need to import the `mongodb` package before using the statement above for this to work.

```
const mongo = require('mongodb')
```

Comment: But, it says "mongo" is not defined...

Comment: Updated answer to include require statement

Answer (score 1):

I am using this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-objectid

```
#install
npm install bson-objectid



#EXAMPLES
var ObjectID = require("bson-objectid");

console.log(ObjectID());
console.log(ObjectID("54495ad94c934721ede76d90"));
console.log(ObjectID(1414093117));//time
console.log(ObjectID([ 84, 73, 90, 217, 76, 147, 71, 33, 237, 231, 109, 144 ]));
console.log(ObjectID(new Buffer([ 84, 73, 90, 217, 76, 147, 71, 33, 237, 231, 109, 144 ])));
```